# PCI Compliance for attachment in email

Tags: email, pci-dss

I am wondering if they are any PCI compliance issues around users of a service sending email with attachments that may or may not contain sensitive information through said service?

As an example, if I were to to sign up to a service that lets me generate a document and I send that document to another person through the services web dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking whether a generic email provider such as gmail has PCI compliance issues because of what it's users may do, then **no**.  Consider the DSSv3 definition:

> PCI DSS applies to all entities involved in payment card
>   processing—including merchants, processors, financial institutions,
>   and service providers, as well as all other entities that store,
>   process, or transmit cardholder data and/or sensitive authentication
>   data.

While the situation you're talking about involves a case where the service provider is used to "transmit cardholder data", a generic email provider is not an "entit(y) involved in payment card processing" (at least not insofar as it's customers use it to send email; it may be insofar as it might charge those customers, but that's a separate issue).

The individual sending the mail has PCI obligations because it's their data, the carrier does not because it isn't.